# How to make make solana web.js bot fast

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction, balance

```
const { Keypair } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, createTransferInstruction } = require("@solana/spl-token");
const { Connection, ParsedAccountData, PublicKey, sendAndConfirmTransaction, Transaction } = require("@solana/web3.js");
const bs58 = require('bs58');

let base58PrivateKey = "";

// Decode base58 private key and convert it to a hexadecimal string
let hexPrivateKey = Buffer.from(bs58.decode(base58PrivateKey)).toString('hex');

// Convert the hexadecimal string to a Uint8Array
let uint8PrivateKey = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(hexPrivateKey, 'hex'));

// Create a Solana Keypair using the Uint8Array private key
let FROM_KEYPAIR = Keypair.fromSecretKey(uint8PrivateKey);

//const SOLANA_CONNECTION = new Connection('https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/a83n-ejcaGA2u7wnVdCzsxQuQLrK8ucZ');
const SOLANA_CONNECTION = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com')
const DESTINATION_WALLET = '9UssfpqBzAsaFSx89SqfsCcL6KUq7XfqgGVZdwsaiMPW';
const MINT_ADDRESS = 'GPyzPHuFFGvN4yWWixt6TYUtDG49gfMdFFi2iniTmCkh'; // You must change this value!


async function getNumberDecimals(mintAddress) {
    const info = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.getParsedAccountInfo(new PublicKey(MINT_ADDRESS));
    const result = (info.value?.data.parsed.info.decimals);
    return result;
}

async function checkAndTransferTokens() {
    // Step 1
    console.log(`1 - Getting Source Token Account`);
    let sourceAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        SOLANA_CONNECTION,
        FROM_KEYPAIR,
        new PublicKey(MINT_ADDRESS),
        FROM_KEYPAIR.publicKey
    );
    console.log(`    Source Account: ${sourceAccount.address.toString()}`);

// Step 2
console.log(`2 - Getting Destination Token Account`);
let destinationAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    SOLANA_CONNECTION,
    FROM_KEYPAIR,
    new PublicKey(MINT_ADDRESS),
    new PublicKey(DESTINATION_WALLET)
);
console.log(`    Destination Account: ${destinationAccount.address.toString()}`);

// Step 3
console.log(`3 - Fetching Number of Decimals for Mint: ${MINT_ADDRESS}`);
const numberDecimals = await getNumberDecimals(MINT_ADDRESS);
console.log(`    Number of Decimals: ${numberDecimals}`);

while (true) {
    // Step 4
    try {
        
        console.log(`4 - Checking Balance`);
     
      
        const balance = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.getTokenAccountBalance(sourceAccount.address);
        console.log(`token balance:${balance.value.uiAmount}`)
          
        

        // Step 4.1: Check if the balance is sufficient
        if (balance.value.uiAmount> 0) {
            // Step 5
            console.log(`5 - Creating and Sending Transaction`);
            const tx = new Transaction();
            tx.add(createTransferInstruction(
                sourceAccount.address,
                destinationAccount.address,
                FROM_KEYPAIR.publicKey,
                balance.value.uiAmount * Math.pow(10, numberDecimals)
            ));

            const latestBlockHash = await SOLANA_CONNECTION.getLatestBlockhash('confirmed');
            tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockHash.blockhash;

            // Step 5.1: Send and confirm the transaction
            const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(SOLANA_CONNECTION, tx, [FROM_KEYPAIR]);
            console.log(
                '\x1b[32m', // Green Text
                `   Transaction Success!`,
                `\n    https://solscan.io/tx/${signature}`
            );
        } else {
            // If the balance is not sufficient, log an error and retry
            console.error('Insufficient balance. Retrying...');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('insufficient funds', error);
        // Handle the error as needed

        // Sleep for a moment before retrying
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2500));
        continue; // Continue with the next iteration of the loop
    }

    // Sleep for 1 second before checking again
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
} checkAndTransferTokens()
```

this script taking 25~30 seconds for fetching balance and transfering token, The problem is it taking 14 seconds to update balance how to over come this

Comment: Use a different rpc provider that is closer to your location. Using public ones is expect to have very bad latency

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you're not setting any priority fees, which with the current congestion on Solana means it takes a while for your tx to land in a block. You can add this by adding a `setComputeUnitPrice` to the beginning of your tx. Check out the [Solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction) for the exact details on this & adjust the microLamport price parameter until you get the speed you want.